# Why am I getting an error when trying to Fill Down using Active Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for specific terms and count the number of occurrences of that term within that column. I am using this macro by copying and pasting a macro button into my active sheet as the name of the worksheet I'll be applying this to will always be different/changing (each sheet is named for a month of the year so it will be changing every time I have a new month's worth of data). The length of the column is also variable with every given month.

This used to work without issue but recently I began getting a 1004 application defined or object defined error at the line that reads:

```
.Range("P7:R7").Formula = strFormulas
```

Are my formulas too long? Here's all of the code I am using for this section:

```
With ActiveSheet.Columns("P:T")
.ColumnWidth = 10
End With

Range("P6").Value = "DeptShortName"
Range("Q6").Value = "IfCAN"
Range("R6").Value = "Business Unit Name"
Range("S6").Value = "Business Unit"

Dim lastRow As Long

'Set formulas to appear in columns 1, 2, 3 after column O
Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

'Set last row to fill for columns P-R based on variable length of column O
lastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Auto fill formulas defined below to columns 1,2, 3 after column O, so columns P, Q, R
    With ActiveSheet
        strFormulas(1) = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CCS"",O7)),""CCS"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""DSO"",O7)),""DSO"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ALC"",O7)),""ALC"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""RCD"",O7)),""RCD"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CMNA"",O7)),""CMNA"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CRNA"",O7)),""CRNA"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CCSCAN"",O7)),""CCSCAN"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CARLYLE"",O7)),""CARLYLE"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CRS"",O7)),""CRS"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ICP"",O7)),""ICP"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MISCELLANEOUS"",O7)),""MISC"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""NAO"",O7)),""NAO DIST"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""NATIONAL"",O7)),""NATIONAL"",""""))))))))))))"
        strFormulas(2) = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CCSCAN"",O7)),""CAN"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ALC 0211"",O7)),""CAN"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ALC 0218"",O7)),""CAN"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ALC 0251"",O7)),""CAN"",""""))))"
        strFormulas(3) = "=CONCATENATE(P7,Q7)"
        .Range("P7:R7").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("P7:R" & lastRow).FillDown
    End With
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use an array like that? How do you expect the formulas to fill in? `strFormulas(1)` for column P, `2` for Q, etc?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on end of the first formula. @BruceWayne seems to write the formulas correctly across that section.

Comment: You also don't need to `FillDown`, simply `.Range("P7:R" & lastRow).Formula = strFormulas`

Comment: By the way, a much nicer formula to use would be an array `INDEX/MATCH` formula, for example, `=INDEX({"CCS","DSO","ALC","RCD","CMNA","CRNA","CCSCAN","CARLYLE","CRS","ICP","MISCELLANEOUS","NAO","NATIONAL"},MATCH(1,COUNTIF(O7,"*"&{"CCS","DSO","ALC","RCD","CMNA","CRNA","CCSCAN","CARLYLE","CRS","ICP","MISCELLANEOUS","NAO","NATIONAL"}&"*"),0))`. That would return the criteria found in `O7`.

Comment: @dwirony, that's indeed more elegant; I tried this and it works nicely, but only if I put double quotes around the strings. Single quotes raise a syntax error. Not sure why...

Comment: @BigBen, the missing parenthesis indeed solves the puzzle. Still trying to learn the culture around here: why wouldn't you post that as an answer rather than a comment? (I can't seem to find any discussion on "answers as comments" on Meta, only the other way around...)

Comment: @Egalth because this is just a simple typo, and I voted to close the question.

Comment: @BigBen - DOH! I forgot to add the extra parenthesis after adding the additional search term. It worked. Thank you so much and thank you all for your contributions. I am VERY inexperienced with writing code and definitely don't know how to write things elegantly!